# Scala - unit test setup (use access modifier qualifiers?)

Tags: unit-testing, scala, scope, tdd

I'm new to Scala (from Java) and I like to develop TDD/BDD. So before knowing much about Scala I've already dived into Scalatest.

I'm wondering what you think is a good access strategy for unit testing, from the viewpoint that you want to test as much as possible.

Suppose I have a class World that I want to test and a class Agent that should not know everything about the World.

```
package program {
  package world {
    class World {
      private var notForAgent
      def forAgentDuringActing
      // forAgentDuringActing has an important side effect in notForAgent
    } 
  }

  package agent {
    class Agent
    // would call World.forAgentDuringActing
  }

  package world.test {
    class WorldSpec extends FunSpec {
      describe("The world") {
        it("should have side-effect behaviour when the agent acts on it") {
          // ... the test ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that these package declarations are not sacred to me.
What I really would like, is that WorldSpec would be something like a companion object to World, so that it can test for the side effect.

I thought maybe access modifier qualifiers would help. I could say `private[world] notForAgent`, but that really is more access than I would like. What I actually would like is something like `private[this, test.WorldSpec] notForAgent`, but I don't think multiple qualifiers are allowed.

What would you do to make this testable? Alternatively, can you indicate where my thoughts go in the wrong direction?

p.s. I know the statement "never test privates". But I also know the opinion "Testing is more important than the code itself. Alter access modifiers if it's needed for testing". However, I would like to avoid that discussion in this thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're asking "How to test private methods?", then ScalaTest actually supports this. See [here](http://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/1.0/org/scalatest/PrivateMethodTester.html).

```
class C {
  private def m(x: Int) = x
}

class CTests extends /*any test suite you like*/ with PrivateMethodTester {
  val decoratedM = PrivateMethod[Int]('m)
  val c = new C
  val actual = c invokePrivate decoratedM(4711)
  val expected = 4711
  actual should be(expected) // this line depends on the test suite you've chosen
}
```

Comment: Yes, I knew about that. However, the state I want to test is in a var, not a method. Still, your answer is actually usable, because apparently Scala also makes a getter method for a private val. So you can do the tests this way.

Wouldn't there be a way to allow this in a more natural way however (such as is the case with a companion object)?

Comment: Hmm, I can't vote up your answer because I don't have 15 reputation yet... :(

Comment: Now that I'm implementing some tests in this fashion I have to say the air becomes a bit code-smelly. For one thing, this test breaks after a refactor (which isn't a big deal, but not clean either). I someone has ideas on how to improve the setup, that would be nice as well. I really like the idea of a companion-like unit test object, but I wouldn't know how to achieve something like that (if possible).

Comment: Testing private methods is not a big issue IMHO. Most of the time it is enough to test them through the public API. If not, then use the solution provided by ScalaTest (it won't be smelly, because it won't happen often). And if you can't use the ScalaTest solution, then feel free to make the method package private. It is not ideal, but it is good enough (again because it won't happen often).